# Introducing novel genes to an adult multicellular organism?

Tags: genetics

Is it possible to introduce a novel gene into the genome of every cell (or at least most cells) of an adult multicellular organism? How would this be done?

Thanks,

CDB

Comment: How multicellular? Are you referring to sponges or mammals? What is "most"? Does the gene need to be expressed as well? You need to give more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, in theory yes, in reality, at the current state of the art, no.

I guess you are speaking about higher organisms (such as mice or humans), if you are referring to small non-complex multicellular organisms then the answer is yes as far as you can transfect every cells with the system described hereafter.

The most promising technique is using the [CRISPR/Cas9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR) system which has already been used to create all types of modified organisms but starting from the embryo. Here a good Nature reference http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v32/n4/full/nbt.2842.html.

There are no ways, at the moment, to transfect an entire organism with the full system. The most recent attempts I heard off is to target specific cells using an encapsulation techniques that only merges with the membrane of specific cells therefore delivering the CRISPR/Cas9 system in a targeted manner. This was in an attempt to knock-out a defined genomic regions in those specific cells, not to introduce a new gene.

I believe in the near future that this will be possible. Not necessarily every cells of an organism but at least some specific cell types.